# How can I subscribe and unsubscribe from an observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I have two functions where I need to subscribe to an observable in the first one, and unsubscribe to it in the second. But in my code , I can't access the observable from the second function because it's not in its scope.

here are my functions :

```
 start() {
    this.max = this.duration;
    const interval = Observable.interval(this.selectedSprint.duration);
    interval
      .takeWhile(_ => !this.isFinished)
      .do(i => this.current += 1)
      .subscribe();
    }

    stop() {
    // here I need to unsybscribe to the observable
    this.dialogService.openConfirmDialog('do you want to stop ?')
      .afterClosed().subscribe((result: boolean) => {
        if (result) {
    // if true logic
        }
      });
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to store the subscription in your component.

```js
export class Component {
  interval$: Subscription;

  start() {
    this.max = this.duration;
    this.interval$ = Observable.interval(this.selectedSprint.duration)
      .takeWhile(_ => !this.isFinished)
      .do(i => this.current += 1)
      .subscribe();
  }

  stop() {
    // here I need to unsybscribe to the observable
    this.dialogService.openConfirmDialog('do you want to stop ?')
      .afterClosed().subscribe((result: boolean) => {
        if (result) {
          this.interval$.unsubscribe();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

**EDIT to answer OP's comment**

```js
export class Component {
  intervalSub$: Subscription;
  intervalObs: Observable<number>;

  start() {
    this.max = this.duration;
    this.intervalObs$ = Observable.interval(this.selectedSprint.duration)
      .takeWhile(_ => !this.isFinished)
      .do(i => this.current += 1);
   this.intervalSub$ = intervalObs.subscribe();
  }

  stop() {
    // here I need to unsybscribe to the observable
    this.dialogService.openConfirmDialog('do you want to stop ?')
      .afterClosed().subscribe((result: boolean) => {
        if (result) {
          this.intervalSub$.unsubscribe();
        }
    });
  }
  /**
   * If you unsubscribed from the interval and you want to resume
   * (If this.isFinished is true, it won't do a thing)
   */
  resume() {
    this.intervalObs.subscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution but I keep getting this : Type 'Observable<number>' is missing the following properties from type 'Subscription': closed, add, remove, unsubscribe ts(2739)

Comment: You must have assigned your interval$ field just after your `do()`, which is an Observable. To be able to unsubscribe, you need to assign the result of your `subscribe()` to this field.

Comment: just one question , can I subscribe to it again after the unsubscription ?  if (!result)

Comment: Yes, but to do that, you'd need to store the subscription AND the observable => You can subcribe to an observable and unsubscribe from a subscription.

Comment: Okay , thank you , can you show me an example of that ?

Answer (score 2):

Save a reference to your subscription in your class with `this.sub = interval.[...].subscribe()`.

This way, you cann cal `this.sub.unsubscribe()` in your second function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a class, you can keep the `subscription` object, returned by the call to `.subscribe()`, as a property.

```
start() {
   this.max = this.duration;
   const interval = Observable.interval(this.selectedSprint.duration);
   interval
     .takeWhile(_ => !this.isFinished)
     .do(i => this.current += 1);
   this.intervalSubscription = interval.subscribe();
}
```

This will allow you to unsubscribe in your `stop` method

```
stop() {
    this.intervalSubscription.unsubscribe(...);
}
```